# Filter results using bash

Tags: json, linux, terminal, jq, conditional-operator

To be more clear, look at the below text file.

```
https://brianbrandt.dk/web/var/www/public_html/.htpasswd
https://brianbrandt.dk/web/var/www/public_html/wp-config.php
https://briannajackson1.wordpress.org/high-entropy-misc.txt
https://briannajackson1.wordpress.org/Homestead.yaml
https://brickellmiami.centric.hyatt.com/dev
https://brickellmiami.centric.hyatt.com/django.log
https://brickellmiami.centric.hyatt.com/.dockercfg
https://brickellmiami.centric.hyatt.com/docker-compose.yml
https://brickellmiami.centric.hyatt.com/.docker/config.json
https://brickellmiami.centric.hyatt.com/Dockerfile
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/web/var/www/public_html/config.php
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/web/var/www/public_html/wp-config.php
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/wp-config.php
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/.wp-config.php.swp
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/_wpeprivate/config.json
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/yarn-debug.log
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/yarn-error.log
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/yarn.lock
https://brideonashoestring.wordpress.org/.yarnrc
https://bridgehome.adobe.com/etc/shadow
https://bridgehome.adobe.com/phpinfo.php
https://bridgetonema.wordpress.org/manifest.json
https://bridgetonema.wordpress.org/manifest.yml
https://bridge.twilio.com/.wp-config.php.swp
https://bridge.twilio.com/wp-content/themes/.git/config
https://bridge.twilio.com/_wpeprivate/config.json
https://bridge.twilio.com/yarn-debug.log
https://bridge.twilio.com/yarn-error.log
https://bridge.twilio.com/yarn.lock
https://bridge.twilio.com/.yarnrc
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/config.lua
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/config.php
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/config.php.txt
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/config.rb
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/config.ru
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/_config.yml
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/console
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/.credentials
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/CVS/Entries
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/CVS/Root
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/dasbhoard/
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/data
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/data.txt
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/db/dbeaver-data-sources.xml
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/db/dump.sql
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/db/.pgpass
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/db/robomongo.json
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/README.txt
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/RELEASE_NOTES.txt
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/.remote-sync.json
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/Resources.zip.manifest
https://brightside.mtn.co.za/.rspec
https://br.infinite.sx/db/dump.sql
https://br.infinite.sx/graphiql
```

The domain name brightside.mtn.co.za and other domains repeated more than 10 times now i want to drop brightside.mtn.co.za and other domains that are repeated more than 10 times and then the output the results the output  should look like.

```
https://br.infinite.sx/db/dump.sql
https://br.infinite.sx/graphiql
https://bridgetonema.wordpress.org/manifest.json
https://bridgetonema.wordpress.org/manifest.yml
```

Comment: The requirements are unclear.  It would therefore be helpful if you could devise a small but informative example showing both the input and the expected output.  See e.g. [mcve].

Comment: Vishnu - You changed the question so much that it now has nothing to do with JSON!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text input is in input.txt, then one solution using jq at the bash command line would be:

```
< input.txt jq -Rr '[inputs] 
  | group_by( sub("/[^/]*$";"") )
  | map(select(length < 10) )
  | .[][]'
```

(If you want the output as JSON strings, omit the -r option.)

### A more efficient solution

The above solution uses the built-in filter `group_by/1` and is thus somewhat inefficient.  For a very large number of input lines, a more efficient solution would be:

```
< input.txt jq -Rr '
  def GROUPS_BY(stream; f):
    reduce stream as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x] ) | .[] ;

  GROUPS_BY(inputs;  sub("/[^/]*$";""))
  | select(length < 10) 
  | .[]'
```

Answer (score 1):

[The following is a response to the original question, which was premised on JSON input.]

Since you need to count the items in a group, it would appear that you will find `group_by( sub("/[^/]*$";"") )` useful.

For example, if you wanted to omit large groups entirely, as one interpretation of the stated requirements would seem to imply, you could use the following filter:

```
[.results[] | select(.status==301) | .url]
| group_by( sub("/[^/]*$";"") )
| map(select(length < 10) )
| .[][]
```